# Change div Background Image when hovering on another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an interactive map on which some continents are highligthed when you hover on them and I am using multiple images to do so. Concretely, I am trying to change the background-image set in one div when I hover on certain parts of the background.

In the CSS code, I am using the tilde selector but it does not seem to work. Could you help me finding the issue please?

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<div class="map">
 <div class="americas">
 </div>

 <div class="emeari">
 </div>

 <div class="emeari2">
 </div>

 <div class="ap">
 </div>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
 .map {
  position:fixed;
  background-image: url(World_Map.jpg); 
  width:960px;
  height:540px;
 }


.americas {
  position:absolute;
  width:364.8px;
  height:540px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.emeari {
  position: absolute;
  width: 297.6px;
  height: 540px;
  left: 364.8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.emeari2 {
  position:absolute;
  width:297.6px;
  height:183.6px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ap {
  position:absolute;
  width:297.6px;
  height:356.4px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Hover */

.americas:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Americas_Map.jpg);
}

.emeari:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Emeari_Map.jpg);
}

.emeari2:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Emeari_Map.jpg);
}

.ap:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Asia_Map.jpg);
}
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: Do you want to show the entire "continent" image as the background image when hovered on a particular continent? 
Also, provide us with codepen/jsfiddle and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

The `~` selector is the sibling selector, it can only select elements at the same level. In your code .map is the parent element and there is no "parent" selector in CSS.

You can fix this however by moving `.map` inside and wrapping in a container element.

```css
.map,
.map-wrapper {
  position:fixed;
  width:960px;
  height:540px;
}

.map {
  background-image: url(World_Map.jpg);
  z-index: -1;
}


.americas {
  position:absolute;
  width:364.8px;
  height:540px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.emeari {
  position: absolute;
  width: 297.6px;
  height: 540px;
  left: 364.8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.emeari2 {
  position:absolute;
  width:297.6px;
  height:183.6px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ap {
  position:absolute;
  width:297.6px;
  height:356.4px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* Hover */

.americas:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Americas_Map.jpg);
}

.emeari:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Emeari_Map.jpg);
}

.emeari2:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Emeari_Map.jpg);
}

.ap:hover ~ .map{
  background-image: url(Asia_Map.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="map-wrapper">
   <div class="americas"></div>

   <div class="emeari"></div>

   <div class="emeari2"></div>

   <div class="ap"></div>
   
   <div class="map"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is currently no parent selector in CSS, but you can achieve this using JS. In this example I'm using jQuery to update the parent's background color (you would have to update the background image).

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ljk8grs/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class="map">
 <div class="americas">
 </div>

 <div class="emeari">
 </div>

 <div class="emeari2">
 </div>

 <div class="ap">
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.map {
  position:fixed;
  background-image: url(World_Map.jpg); 
  width:960px;
  height:540px;
 }


.americas {
  position:absolute;
  width:364.8px;
  height:540px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.emeari {
  position: absolute;
  width: 297.6px;
  height: 540px;
  left: 364.8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.emeari2 {
  position:absolute;
  width:297.6px;
  height:183.6px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ap {
  position:absolute;
  width:297.6px;
  height:356.4px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JS

```
$(".americas").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background", "red"); // CHANGE IMAGE PROPERTY HERE
});

$(".emeari").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background", "blue"); // CHANGE IMAGE PROPERTY HERE
});

$(".emeari2").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background", "green"); // CHANGE IMAGE PROPERTY HERE
});

$(".ap").hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().css("background", "orange"); // CHANGE IMAGE PROPERTY HERE
});
```